# Trying to store the performing time of a program into an array, but array elements always show the same value

Tags: c, arrays, time

I am calculating the running time of a program with different input data, using C.
I am running the program 100 times and want to find the average running time.
In order to find the average, I want to store each running time value into an array, however the values stored always show the same number.

I have tried changing float type to long and double, but it did not work.
I added a print statement to show the values and they are the values I want, only they get changed once inserted into the array.

```
// C programming
int main(){

clock_t t;
int n, m = 0;
int arr_time[100]; // also tried changing the array type from int to float
int repeat, repeat_times = 1000;

for(n=1;n<100;++n)
{
    t = clock();
    for (repeat=0;repeat<repeat_times; ++repeat)
    {
        some_function();
    }

    t = clock()-t;
    printf("%f", ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/repeat_times); // to check the values to be stored
    arr_time[m] = ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/repeat_times; // values stored are not the same as previous line though
    m+=1;
    printf("It took %f seconds to run some_function(%d)\n",
           ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/repeat_times,n);
}

int sum = 0;
for (n=1;n<100;++n)
{
    sum += arr_time[n];
}
for (n=0;n<10;n++)
{
    printf("(%f)\n", arr[n]); // checking which values are stored into the array
}

printf("(%f)\n", sum);
int average = ((float)sum)/99;
printf("The average time in seconds to run some_function is (%f)\n", average);

return 0;
}
```

How can I store the time value into the array?

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger show you?

Comment: Got it! Floats needs to be stored in arrays of type double

Comment: @Camilla, floats need to be stored in a floating point array. It doesn't have to be double.

Comment: Yes, both float and double types work

Answer (score 0):

```
//...
arr_time[m] = ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/repeat_times;
//you can store them here where arr[] is float    
arr[n] = arr_time[m]
//
for (n=0;n<10;n++)
{
// or use arr_time[] and not arr[] because you are not using arr[] in your program
printf("(%f)\n", arr_time[n]); // checking which values are stored into the array
}
```